# You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

I got an error message when I start a new question

> ***You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.***

My last question was asked **16 hours ago**: see [Difference between angular.copy() and assignment (=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/different-between-angular-copy-and-equal)

My first question asked from **17 hours ago** : see

[Difference between moment.toString() and moment.toISOString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747550/difference-between-moment-tostring-and-moment-toisostring)

The error message says : *You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.*

My question is : When does the 24 hours period start and stop? Does it depend on my first question of yesterday or last question of yesterday?

Comment: I show [4 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2218635/ramesh-rajendran?tab=questions) you've asked, 15/16/18/19 hours ago. You maybe have 2 other questions as well, but you deleted? Also, I'm pretty sure it's based on 6 questions in any 24 hour period. So anytime you try to ask a new question it checks the last 24 hours and if you've already asked 6 questions in the last 24 hours it won't let you ask another.

Comment: Yes i think, i may be deleted that. Yes. But my question is  `When the 24 hours period start and stop? It's depend on my first question of yesterday or last question of yesterday?`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

It's max 6 questions per *any* 24-hour period. There's no reset time - if, in the past 24 hours, you've already asked 6 questions, then you have to wait to ask another one.

To put this another way: you can ask another question 24 hours from the time you asked your 6th-newest question.

Comment: `you can ask another question 24 hours from the time you asked your 6th-newest question.` This is good? or bad?

Comment: @ram that's good. So in 3-4 hours from now you'll be able to ask 2 more new questions!

Comment: Does the deletion of questions changes the timer?

Comment: Nope @vasili111